# Checking if variable is defined before accessing its properties

Tags: javascript, validation

I didn't write this but I noticed it in our codebase at work.

```
var data = object && object.attribute && object.attribute.data ? object.attribute.data : {};
```

I get that the programmer is trying to check that the variable `object.attribute.data`is defined before using it, but is seems like so much repeated code. What's the best way to assign `data` the value of `object.attribute.data` if it's defined, otherwise giving it a value of `{}`?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Are you asking for alternatives for a *ternary operator*? I'd bet your question would get more lovin' if you included the whole function instead, and mentioned that you're worried about the readability of the ternary operator.

Comment: The ternary operator isn't my concern here. I'm trying to figure out the best way to check that `object.attribute.data` is defined before assigning it to another `var`. `object && object.attribute && object.attribute.data` seems like a bad practice since it violates "Do not repeat yourself." I don't think the rest of the function is relevant.

Comment: @blahshaw But it is really no repetition, `object` and `object.attribute` and `object.attribute.data` are three different things having three different values.

Comment: The identifiers in this question are completely generic (akin to `foo` and `bar`), making this question [off-topic](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357) for Code Review.  Feel free to ask it again with real identifiers, preferably with sufficient context so that we might even be able to avoid the null-checking problem altogether.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg they all have different values but it is all boilerplate. The only value they care about is the `data` key and to not throw an exception for dereferencing an `undefined` value.  If they wanted to get a `config` value out of `attribute` the same long expression would be repeated.

Comment: @200_success I might not understand the purpose of codereview, but I think your argument is bemusing. He is asking a syntactical question that is self contained. Contextual information might help prevent this concrete issue, but I am here with the same question. It might belong to stackoverflow, but the question is not bad for your mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
var data = object && object.attribute && object.attribute.data || {};
```

Alternatively, you could create a simple function to safely index objects that may not be defined, such as:

```
function resolve(value) {
    return function(key) {
        return key ? resolve((value || {})[key]) : value;
    };
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
var data = resolve(object)('attribute')('data')() || {};
```

If anything in the chain does not exist, it will return `undefined`. This might be useful if you have deeply nested and unpredictable objects, such as an object resulting from parsing JSON data from a remote resource.

http://jsfiddle.net/VHcdq/1/

Comment: This is a small improvement since it eliminates the need for the ternary operator. However, is there a cleaner way of doing this without needing to write out `object && object.attribute && object.attribute.data`?

Comment: @blahshaw, no, not really, unless you want to assume that `object` and `object.attribute` exist and can have properties, and go straight for `var data = object.attribute.data || {};`