# CodeLess Questions query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange

As part of an exercise by Jamal to clean up old questions on Code Review that have no code in them, I helped by writing this query on Stack Exchange Data Explorer: [CodeLess Questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/323727/codeless-questions)

```
select Id as [Post Link], CreationDate
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 --questions
  and Body not like '%</code></pre>%'
  and ClosedDate is null
order by CreationDate
```

I realize this is a relatively simple query, but I am always looking for ways to avoid `like` conditions (and `not like`), and this query irks me.

Note that the like condition is `%</code></pre>%` - this is to trap the automatically managed code blocks that Stack Exchange uses to identify code. I cannot easily trap the open-tags because sometimes, when a custom syntax is used, the open tags are hard to search on.

I am looking for insights on whether the query can be improved or whether there are alternatives to the systems I have used for identifying code-less questions.

For reference, when Stack Exchange gets a question, the markup is converted to HTML and stored in the `Body` column.

[An example is as follows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54531/checking-if-variable-is-defined-before-accessing-its-properties):

MarkDown:

> ```
> I didn't write this but I noticed it in our codebase at work.
>
>     var data = object && object.attribute && object.attribute.data ? object.attribute.data : {};
>
> I get that the programmer is trying to check that the variable
> `object.attribute.data` is defined before using it, but is seems like
> so much repeated code. What's the best way to assign `data` the value
> of `object.attribute.data` if it's defined, otherwise giving it a
> value of `{}`?
> ```

HTML Encoding:

> ```
> <p>I didn't write this but I noticed it in our codebase at work.</p>
>
> <pre><code>var data = object &amp;&amp; object.attribute &amp;&amp; object.attribute.data ? object.attribute.data : {};
> </code></pre>
>
> <p>I get that the programmer is trying to check that the variable <code>object.attribute.data</code>is defined before using it, but is
> seems like so much repeated code. What's the best way to assign
> <code>data</code> the value of <code>object.attribute.data</code> if
> it's defined, otherwise giving it a value of <code>{}</code>?</p>
> ```

Comment: This would fail for a question where someone uses only the tag `<code>`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel you are supposed to use 4 spaces, if you highlight your code and click the code button it will add 4 spaces to every line so that the markup is done for you.   **And** if you only use `<code>` tags then you aren't formatting it correctly, and that should be handled by an edit anyway, so this query is still serving it's purpose.

Comment: @Lyle'sMug Observe the following code: http://pastebin.com/5xdJXLDk. That one is still valid, and it has the code (almost) properly formated, with missing whitespaces for identation. And this query would fail in it. And yes, the syntax highlighter 'works' with it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - what Lyle'sMug is saying, and I agree with, is that a 'false positive' indicates that there's a problem in the markdown for the question anyway, and an edit to use the standard markdown will both fix the question, and remove it from the SEDE query results.... which is a good thing,

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, I am sure that we can find edge cases where this query is  going to give us too much information, but that is okay, because that is why we are creating the data so that we can weed out the not so elegant posts or the off-topic posts, it wouldn't take more than a second to be able to tell that the example you gave is actually on topic and that it has code

Comment: @rolfl The edge case I provided is actually valid HTML, which is allowed here. I've updated the example with proper indentation: http://pastebin.com/x7repdtP. Is that still a problem in the markdown? According to this website's goal, that piece of code is fine (apart from the missing doctype, `<html>`, `<head>`, `<title>` and `<body>`) and within standards. Honestly, I can't see any problem in using that. It is allowed and it is both valid HTML and markdown, with proper indentation. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lyle'sMug I'm just saying that the query was made with assumption that all the code starts with `<pre><code>` and that isn't always the case.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - Let's take this to chat [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel if the user is using the provided shortcuts for the markdown, then this query will provide all answers without the tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never used it before but I think what you are looking for is `CHARINDEX` I found a [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25676890/1214743) that has several upvotes and no downvotes using it like this

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('</code></pre>', Body) = 0
```

So far from what I have seen they are relatively close to the same speed, and is giving the same results as your query.

I would much rather read this than `Body not like '%</code></pre>%'`

I think we have found a new "hammer", let's find some nails.

<sub>[Read more about CHARINDEX Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)</sub>

---

There is also a `CONTAINS` function in T-SQL, but unfortunately it cannot be used on that column of that table because the column is not Full-Text Indexed

<sub>[Read more about `CONTAINS` Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)</sub>